# How do I use a prior query's result when subtracting an interval in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code:

```
WITH example_var AS 
    (SELECT 3)

SELECT current_date - interval '3 day'
```

How do I use `example_var` in in the interval?

I'd like to do something like `- interval CONCAT(example_var, 'day')` so that I could change what `example_var` is equal to and therefore change the length of interval but that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an interval from a constant value, you can use the `make_interval()` function.

But you need to include `example_var` in the FROM clause. But can't refer to the actual value, you need to define a column alias for that as well.

```
WITH example_var (days) AS (  
  values (3) 
)
SELECT current_date - make_interval(days => v.days)
from example_var v
```

For this specific example, you don't need to use an interval. You can subtract an integer directly from a date.

```
WITH example_var (days) AS (  
  values (3) 
)
SELECT current_date - v.days
from example_var v
```